# Get all column names of all datatable properties from a class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a class like below. It has multiple properties of type DataTable. I am trying to dynamically fetch all the properties and print their column names.

```
public class Example
{
    public DataTable dt1 { get; set; }
    public DataTable dt2 { get; set; }
    ...
    public DataTable dtN { get; set; }
}
```

Expected output:

Table1 Name: dt1
Table1 Columns: col_11, col_12, col_13

Table2 Name: dt2
Table2 Columns: col_21, col_22, col_23

...

TableN Name: dtN
TableN Columns: col_N1, col_N2, col_N3

Comment: "I want to..." that is good to know. Mind to share with us how far you have come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have an object `ex` of type `Example`, you can find the column names of all of the properties by doing:

```
Type exType = ex.GetType();
List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>(exType.GetProperties());
foreach(PropertyInfo prop in props) {
    DataTable thisDT = (DataTable)prop.GetValue(ex);
    var tableName = prop.Name;
    var columnNames = new List<string>();
    foreach(DataColumn column in thisDT.Columns) {
        columnNames.Add(column.Name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Table Name: {tableName}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Column Names: {String.Join(",", columnNames)}");
}
```

Note: this assumes that every one of the properties in Example are DataTables. If not, you need to do a bit more work in the `foreach(PropertyInfo prop in props)` loop.